When does $\mathrm{Bl}_Z(S)\cong\mathrm{Bl}_{Z'}(S')$ for $Z'\hookrightarrow S'$ a base change of $Z\hookrightarrow S$?
Consider a Cartesian diagram of schemes such that horizontal arrows are closed immersions
$$\begin{array}
AZ' & \stackrel{i'}{\longrightarrow} & S' \\
\downarrow{p'} & & \downarrow{p} \\
Z & \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} & S  
\end{array}
$$
It induces a morphism
$$\mathrm{Bl}_{Z'}(S')\to \mathrm{Bl}_Z(S). $$
I want know when $\mathrm{Bl}_{Z'}(S')\cong \mathrm{Bl}_Z(S)$. Here I consider three conditions

$\mathcal{O}_{S,s}\to \mathcal{O}_{S',s'}$ is injective for all points $s'\mapsto s$;
$S'\setminus Z'\cong S\setminus Z$;
For all $s'\mapsto s$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have
$$(\mathcal{I}_{Z',s'})^n\cap \mathcal{O}_{S,s}=(\mathcal{I}_{Z,s})^n,\quad \mathcal{I}_{Z',s'}:=\mathcal{I}_{Z,s}\mathcal{O}_{S',s'}. $$


Conjecture. With the above conditions we have $\mathrm{Bl}_{Z'}(S')\cong \mathrm{Bl}_Z(S)$.

Here is my proof assuming further that $S'$ and $S$ are affine.
Proof.
Let $I\subseteq\mathcal{O}(S)$ be the ideal associated to $Z\hookrightarrow S$. The above conditions are

$\mathcal{O}(S)\subseteq\mathcal{O}(S')$;
$\mathcal{O}(S)[\frac{1}{f}]\cong\mathcal{O}(S')[\frac{1}{f}]$ for all $f\in I$;
for sufficiently large $N$
$$I^n\mathcal{O}(S')\cap \mathcal{O}(S)=I^n.$$With these conditions we can show that (conditions above are for injectivity and surjectivity)$$\mathcal{O}(S)\big[\frac{I}{f}\big]\xrightarrow{\cong} \mathcal{O}(S')\big[\frac{I\mathcal{O}(S')}{f}\big],\quad\forall f\in I $$

QED
The affine case can not cover the situation when $S'=\mathrm{Bl}_Z(S)$ and $Z'$ the exceptional divisor. Here are my questions

Is the conjecture true for general $S'\to S$? We can focus on Noetherian schemes or even varieties.
Can we simply derive it from the affine case?

